# Scoring Formula using multiple record types

Tags: formula

I have a field that is common to several different record types, but the way it is scored is different for each.  I am looking for assistance on how to write a formula that populates the same field differently for all of the different scoring scenarios if possible.

**Example:**  My field is called **Current Ratio** and it is associated with Record Type 1, Record Type 2, and Record Type 3.  For RT 1, I need  the formula to provide a score of '6' if the **Current Ratio** is > 3.00.  For RT 2, I need the formula to provide a score of '6' if the **Current Ratio** is > 2.50.  For RT 3, I need a score of '6' if the **Current Ratio** is > 2.00.

The formula below works as is but does not include the Record Types, but can I include the RTs into this formula without having to create separate formulas for each?

IF( Current_Ratio__c > 3.00,6,
IF( Current_Ratio__c >= 2.25,5,
IF( Current_Ratio__c >= 1.75,4,
IF( Current_Ratio__c >= 1.25,3,
IF( Current_Ratio__c >= 1.00,2,
IF( Current_Ratio__c <= 1.00,1,
0))))))

Thanks in advance for any assistance or feedback!

Comment: You should look into the `CASE` formula function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the `RecordType` merge field for your object and include it in your formula. 
So the format would be `<Your object>.RecordType.Name`
Use it with your existing IF statement or you can even use a CASE statement with your record type name.

Note: Use the RecordType name and dont use the RecordType Id. 
Your formula would take the form:

```
IF( Current_Ratio__c && <Your object>.RecordType.Name='RT1'> 3.00,6, IF( Current_Ratio__c && <Your object>.RecordType.Name='RT2'>= 2.25,5**............**
```

Comment: Thank you Richard!  Pardon my possible ignorance as formulas aren't a strong suit, but when I mirror the formula you have above, I get an error message:   Incorrect parameter type for operator '>'.  Expected Text, received Number

Comment: Take out the brackets...he just meant insert the object name in those places...they're being interpreted as greater than evaluators

Comment: Thanks @Brian Mansfield, I knew what he meant and did not include the brackets in my formula.  Here is the formula that is producing the error.  When I Check Syntax, it highlights the 3.00 for what it's worth.                   IF( 
Current_Ratio__c &&  RecordType.Name ='Commercial'> 3.00,6,
IF( 
Current_Ratio__c &&  RecordType.Name ='CRE Non-Owner'>= 2.25,5
))

Comment: His answer was just giving you a general idea of how to approach it...it's not syntactically correct...the first condition in your initial IF statement is (Current_Ratio__c && RecordType.Name ='Commercial'> 3.00)....do you think that's doing exactly what you want it to do? I recommend reading about basic formula syntax, this is a pretty common use case and will be useful in the future